# Fisher's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In question 2)c)i) here https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/legacy/3333/b08_10_0.pdf then $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = u(1-u-\beta v) + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi^2}$$ and

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = -\delta uv + D\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \xi^2}$$

which we have non-dimensionalised and $\beta$ is a tunable parameter. The question says to assume $D=1$ and show that $\beta$ can be tuned so that $u$ satisfies Fisher's equation $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \delta u(1-u) + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi^2}$$

Then in the solution they say to 'let $v= \frac{(1-\delta)(1-u)}{\beta}$'. Then substituting this into the first equation gives Fisher's equation.

However, I have no idea why you can just let $v= \frac{(1-\delta)(1-u)}{\beta}$. I know that $\beta$ is a tunable parameter but why is it allowed to have $u,v$ dependence?? Furthermore, why would this only be allowed when $D=1$? Doesn't tunable mean it's a constant whose value you can choose?